# Головуючий чи голова

Tags: вибір-слова

При написані доповіді для захисту дипломної роботи виникло питання, як краще сказати "Шановні ***головуючий/голова***, члени державної екзаменаційної комісії, науковий керівник та присутні, до Вашої уваги пропонується захист дипломної роботи на тему ..."

СУМ-20

> **[ГОЛОВУЮЧИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19163&page=653)** Той, хто головує на зборах, засіданні й т. ін.
>
> **[ГОЛОВА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19119&page=652)** **3.** ч. і ж. Особа, яка веде збори, засідання і т. ін.

Чи має значення, яке використати слово? Яке слово стилістично правильніше використовувати?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вживання дієприкметників активного стану з -уч-, -юч- не рекомендовано нормами сучасної української мови.

Замініть головуючий на варіант: голова, або перебудуйте речення, використавши дієслово головувати.

НЕ РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО
Головуючий і секретар зборів вважаються обраними, якщо за кожного з них проголосувала більшість суддів.

РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО
Голова і секретар зборів вважаються обраними, якщо за кожного з них проголосувала більшість суддів.

[джерело](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/)